Getting wrong polar coordinates

I want to get the polar coordinates of point D. I chose $ \theta = 3\pi/2 $ for point D and solved for $r$. But I get $r = -2$, so coordinate would be $(-2, 3\pi/2)$ but this point is the topmost one and not D. Am I doing something wrong ?
Thanks

How did you determine the graph of $~r = 2 \cos(2\theta) ~?~$  That is, either $~r~$ is allowed to be negative or it isn't.  If $~r~$ is not allowed to be negative, then $~\cos(2\theta)~$ is not allowed to be negative.

Try using the polar law defining the curve you have to obtain its cartesian parametric equations. Set $t=2\theta\in [0,\pi]$ (assuming $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$), from which you get $\theta=t/2$ and $r=2\cos(t)$, so by substituting
\begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\theta)=2\cos(t)\cos(t/2) \\
y=r\sin(\theta)=2\cos(t)\sin(t/2)
\end{cases}
for $t\in [0,\pi]$. This way, with $t=\pi$ you get $D=(0,-2)$.
Hope it helps.

When I did the orientation of the curve as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, point D occurs when $\theta = \pi/2$.  So, that makes sense now. So, polar coordinates of point D are $(-2, \pi/2)$

In polar coordinates, the first component (corresponding to the polar radius), cannot be negative by definition. So, if you want the polar coordinates of the point D in the orientation you described, they should be $(2,\pi/2)$.

In the book I am using (Precalculus by Cohen) author defines $r$ in both ways. If $r$ is positive, then you go towards right on x-axis from origin and then trace angle $\theta$. If $\theta$ is positive, then you go counter clockwise and its negative then you go clockwise. If $r$ is negative, then you go towards left on x-axis from origin and then trace the angle.

@user9026 See my comment following the posted question.  The convention of allowing negative $~r~$ that is apparently adopted (or temporarily adopted) by the author is viable but (arguably) non-standard.  While it is reasonable to presume that you had no way of noticing this when you posted the question, you should have reacted to my comment by immediately editing your posted question to include the (apparent) convention that is (? temporarily ?) adopted by the author (AKA problem composer).
